# Sort order of Tag Pages

Tags: products, sorting, tags, product-tag

Can someone tell me the file where sort order of "Tagged" pages can be changed. Somehow, my tag pages are ranking better in SEO and I would like to change the sort order of products that are displayed for better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following these steps to see what sort order the tag pages have and change it accordingly then to your needs:

I would say you should look what´s in your local.xml

1. look for Default Sort set in Category page in Magento administration, if not set then
2. look for Default Sort set in configuration for Store, if not set then
3. look for Default Sort set in configuration for Website, if not set then
4. look for Default Sort set in configuration for Default Config, if not set then

Note that configuration could be in database, table core_config_data, or config.xml file `(for sorting – app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml around line 723. – position)`.

And that’s why you have default sorting by Position (“Best Value”) for category view page.